# Adding a router to an existing wired network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm trying to connect a Belkin Wireless G+ MIMO Modem Router to a switch port as I don't have any other option to lay a network for two PCs. I do know that a router has in-built routing capabilities which we don't need to configure, as it will auto-connect to the network.

When a user connects to that router wirelessly, Internet stops working on the PC.

What should  I do to configure this properly?

Comment: *"But what I want to know is when a user connect to that router wirelessly, LAN internet doesn't turn on"* – can you clarify what that means?

Comment: say for example; I've connected one cable from switch to router without configuring anything & also another cable from pc to the router.. so the router identifies default GW trough the network & assign IP's on the same series but not issued by the router.. Further, internet stops working on the PC soon as a wireless client connects to that available default network in that router (belking).

Answer (score 2):

If you had Internet connection provided through the switch before, there is probably already a DHCP server and router in your network, acting as the default gateway.

If so, you need to disable the router's DHCP and routing services entirely, because otherwise it'd conflict with the existing router.

Therefore:

- disable the router's DHCP
- assign the router a fixed IP (e.g. by giving it a static lease from the existing DHCP server or router, or giving it a non-DHCP leased IP address)
- make sure you don't connect anything to the router's WAN port (the single one meant for modems)

This way, your router will act like a "normal" switch, just passing on packets through WiFi or the four ports at the back.